# Display information of one user from the list

Tags: angular, typescript

There is such a list of users:

```
<div class="list-group" >
  <div class="media" *ngFor="let user of users">
    <a class="list-group-item ">
      <h4 class=" media-heading list-group-item-heading"> {{user.surname_first_name}} </h4>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <p class="list-group-item-text">{{user.position}}</p>     
       </div>
     </div>      
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And next to it there is a block where full information about the user is displayed. Here's a small piece:

```
<div class="card-content">
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group form-black label-floating is-empty">
           <label class="control-label">Surname</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]='user.surname' name="surname" >
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class="form-group form-black label-floating is-empty">
           <label class="control-label">Name</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]='user.name' name="name" >
          </div>
        </div>
        ....
     </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here's how to make it so that by clicking on a specific list user, its data is displayed in a block with information.

Comment: Is there a block for each user, or just one block where the selected user's information is displayed?

Comment: I would like to output one block

Comment: and the information should change in the block if another user is selected

Comment: do your users have a unique reference, like ID or something? I'm thinking bind a click event to list-group-items which updates a variable (something like selectedUser), which you then use to populate your block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a click event binding to your .list-group-item, that updates a variable (selectedUser) with the selected user's data. Your block can then pull the data from selectedUser.

User List html:

```
<div class="list-group" >
  <div class="media" *ngFor="let user of users">
    <a class="list-group-item" (click)="updateSelectedUser(user.id)">
      <h4 class=" media-heading list-group-item-heading"> {{user.surname_first_name}} </h4>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <p class="list-group-item-text">{{user.position}}</p>     
       </div>
     </div>      
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Block html:

```
<div class="card-content">
  <form>
    <div *ngIf="selectedUser" class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group form-black label-floating is-empty">
           <label class="control-label">Surname</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]='selectedUser.surname' name="surname" >
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class="form-group form-black label-floating is-empty">
           <label class="control-label">Name</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]='selectedUser.name' name="name" >
          </div>
        </div>
        ....
     </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Component TS file:

```
....
export class YourComponentName  {

  selectedUser = null;

  users = [
    {'id': 1, 'position': 1, 'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Adams'},
    {'id': 2, 'position': 2, 'first_name': 'Joan', 'last_name': 'Smith'}
  ]

  updateSelectedUser(userId) {
    this.selectedUser = this.users.find(el => {
      return el.id === userId
    })
  }
}
```

Here's a stackblitz that shows a proof of concept https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hnjt3f

Answer (score 0):

You could 'Output' the selected user from the list and then 'Input' this user to the information block you are making. Try making two different components and a parent component handling all delegations.

You may refer to https://embed.plnkr.co/OeUYze7djU90AWmc2Sno/ to get a feeling of how to use @Input and @Output.